# Text Entry Frequently Lags with the Full Site Theme on Mobile Chrome on an LG G3

Tags: support, mobile-web, full-site

I just switched from using Mobile-Chrome on an iPhone 5 to using Mobile-Chrome on an LG G3.

While using the Full Site theme, Stack Exchange frequently crashed Mobile-Chrome on my iPhone 5. Without any research or supporting evidence, I attributed the crashing to the fact that Mobile-Chrome simply had issues on iOS.

But now that I'm over on Android 4.4, I'm seeing different issues. Frequently, when typing an answer, the text box lags and stops echoing my text input.

I know that the Stack Exchange JavaScript code is actively listening to my text input so that it can display a preview window, periodically save a draft, and other things; but I also know that Mobile-Chrome, or even the LG G3 could be at fault as well.

So I wanted to submit my experience to see if anyone else was experiencing the same thing.

**EDIT**: In response to @Shadow Wizard's comment, as a matter of fact, I *have* been using the **Full Site** theme on my phone. So is correct to assume that the Full Site theme have more intense JavaScript that might not work on Mobile-Chrome?

Comment: If you're using the full site theme, is it any better?

Comment: Oh, seeing your edit my question turns to "If you're using the mobile web theme, is it any better"? :)